# How should the WPF code look to achieve nested reusability

Tags: c#, xaml, controls

This is a simple case, that I am having difficulty understanding nesting types in xaml.
Say you have a myusercontrol.xaml

and you want to declarativly pass data to it like this:

```
  <my:MyUserControl x:Name="myUserControl1" >
        <my:PointCollection>
            <my:point>33,12</my:point>
            <my:point>11,12</my:point>
        </my:PointCollection>
        <my:PointCollection>
            <my:point>33,12</my:point>
            <my:point>11,12</my:point>
        </my:PointCollection>
    </my:MyUserControl>
```

What would MyUserControl.xaml/.cs have to look like to accept this Enumeration of Point collection dependency.

Second question would be, how do i reformulate the xaml usage above so that i can databind to a Enumerable to myUserControl1.DataContext.

Answer (score 0):

For databinding to an enumerable, use a [Collection View](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview.aspx).  See the Remarks and Examples sections.

```
<MyUserControl.DataContext>
  <Binding Source="{StaticResource pointCollection}"/>
</MyUserControl.DataContext>
```